# Are the chest level unlockables required for Platinum God?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, wrath-of-the-lamb

In the most recent update after beating the most recent boss holding the Polaroid. You can unlock a special chest level which beaten by each character unlocks a new trinket. Are these items required for Platinum God?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edmund McMillen [confirmed](http://www.formspring.me/EdmundM/q/340266076149408980) that, with version 1.333, they are necessary, along with every other secret in the game.